# Sending an email when an Exception is Thrown

Tags: java, exception

I have written a java class where if a method throws an exception, an email is sent, via java mail, with a report to the administrators.

It works - my question is w.r.t elegance - to catch the exception thrown by the main method, the sendEmail() method resides in the catch block of the main method. The sendEmail() method  has its own try-catch block.

In effect - it looks like below - is there a more beautiful way of writing this?

```
try {  
    foo;  
}  
catch {  
   try{  
    sendEmail();  
  }  
  catch {  
   log(e.message);  
  }  
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java can have nested try / catch blocks.

If you'd like, you can move the try / catch sendmail block to another method.  When the try / catch blocks are more complex, it will make the code easier to understand.

Answer (score 20):

If you want something "more elegant", one simple suggestion is to have your `sendEmail` helper method catch and log the email exceptions.  (I don't imagine you want the exceptions to propagate ... or do some other recovery ...)

---

However, there is something *more important* to say.  What you are implementing here is the **wrong approach** to reporting errors.

- If something goes badly wrong with your application there is a chance that you will SPAM the administrator with multiple emails reporting the same problem over, and over, and over ...
- By sending emails from deep within your code, you are making it hard for the administrator to integrate your application's error reporting.

A better approach is to report the problem via a Java logging frame such as Log4J.  If the administrator wants to he / she can configure some kind of monitoring system like LogWatch, Nagios, etc, etc.  Such a monitoring system will detect and classify errors, anomalies, etc (like your application's errors) in the various logger streams, de-dup them, and **if the administrator configures it** send a notification via email, pager or whatever.

Comment: +1, always decouple application code from site-operations monitoring (contacting admins etc.)